# Mapping event.getRawX() and event.getX()

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'm developing drawing application I'm using `event.getRawX()` to get the screen touch information .I want  correct mapping of the `event.getRawX()` and `event.getX()` in android canvas draw area .how to achieve this?

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

try to do something like this

```
public boolean onTouch(final View v, final MotionEvent event) {

    int rawXCord, rawYCord;
    final int actionIndex = event.getAction() >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT;
    final int location[] = { 0, 0 };
    v.getLocationOnScreen(location);
    rawXCord= (int) event.getX(actionIndex) + location[0];
    rawYCord= (int) event.getY(actionIndex) + location[1];

    //do ahead accordingly

}
```